# How to map a response object to a Type interface consisting of a few other Type Interfaces in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, casting, angular-cli

I have the following interface:

```
export interface ObjLookup {
    owner?: IObjOwner;
    contacts?: IOwnerContacts[];
    location?: IOwnerLocation;
}
```

And that includes the following interfaces:

```
export interface IObjOwner {
    lastName?: string,
    firstName?: string;
}

export interface IOwnerContacts {
    name?: string;
    address?: string;
    email?: string;
}

export interface IOwnerLocation {
    address?: string;
    city?: string;
    state?: string;
    zip?: number;
    country?: string;
}
```

Now, my response object looks kind of like this:

```
{
    status: "success",
    is_error: false,
    errors: [],
    data: {
        owner: {
            lastName: "lovejoy",
            firstName: "reverend"
        }, 
        contacts: [
            {
                  name: "homer simpson",
                  address: "3 evergreen terrace, springfield, XX XX823",
                  email: "homer@springfieldnuclearpower.net"
            },
            {
                  name: "ned flanders",
                  address: "5 evergreen terrace, springfield, XX XX823",
                  email: "ned@somechurch.god"
            }
        ],
        location: {
            address: "the church",
            city: "Springfield",
            state: "XX",
            zip: XX823,
            country: "US"
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore any syntax errors in the json response as i typed it out.

Anyways, I think I need to do something along the lines of mapping a response with observables and piping and other stuff. What I have so far is:

```
export class SimpsonsService {
     public resourceUrl = 'www.example.com/api/simpsons';

     constructor ( protected http: HttpClient) {}

    find(name: string): Observable<EntityResponseType> {

        return this.http.get<ObjLookup>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${name}`)
           .pipe(
               map(respObj => {
                   const
               })
           );
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple renditions where I need to extract the response object and create a few individual types mapped to the various interfaces, and then need to include those as part of a greater response type `ObjLookup`.

What do I need to do in order to catch the appropriate data objects as part of the `response.data.owner`, `response.data.contacts`, `response.data.location` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Simply typecast

```
    <IObjOwner>response.data.owner
    <Array<IOwnerContacts>>response.data.contacts
    <IOwnerLocation>response.data.location
```

For `data wasnt a property of response`, you have to either make return type of `response` object as `any`. Or create a new interface with all the properties of response object and provide the type of that interface to `response` object.
Say,

```
export interface IDataResponse {
    owner?: IObjOwner;
    contacts?: Array<IOwnerContacts>;
    location?: IOwnerLocation
}

export interface IResponse {
    status?: string;
    is_error?: boolean;
    errors?: Array<any>;
    data?: IDataResponse;
}
```

And use as,

```
owner:  IObjOwner;
contacts: Array<IOwnerContacts> = [];
location: IOwnerLocation;

return this.http.get<ObjLookup>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${name}`)
           .pipe(
               map((response: IResponse)=> {
                  this.owner =  <IObjOwner>response.data.owner
                  this.contacts =  <Array<IOwnerContacts>>response.data.contacts
                  this.locations = <IOwnerLocation>response.data.location
               })
           );
   });
```

Comment: @BarryChapman, i am sorry, i was writing the explanation for your question.

Comment: So - you are saying that angular requires you to create models/types for /every/ single api response scheme there possibly is? I don't believe that, it would be an insane amount of work. I just want to parse out a few pieces of the response object

Comment: Its not angular, its typescript that is asking you to give Object type or data type. If unsure about the type, you can use `any`

Comment: I am sure about the type(s) - I just want to make sure that the response object is mapped properly and such

Comment: @BarryChapman please see, the new updated answer with all the interfaces and their usage.

Comment: So - it seems that it has issue with the `contacts: Array<IOwnerContacts> = [];` - it says that it expects an expression

Comment: @BarryChapman, i can't say because now i have changed every code into typescript data type.

Comment: Becasue, its just typecasting and assigning value from an object to the destinated object, please search more and you will get that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
owner:  IObjOwner;
contacts: IOwnerContacts[];
location: IOwnerLocation;

return this.http.get<ObjLookup>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${name}`)
           .pipe(
               map(respObj => {
                   this.owner= respObj.data.owner
                   this.contacts= respObj.data.contacts
                   this.location= respObj.data.location
                   //do something
               })
           );
        });
```

Comment: yea.it will be inferred by the return type

Comment: .map(respObj ) should return something

Comment: Where does the return occur in the map

Comment: About map, read here : https://blog.angularindepth.com/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2

Comment: for example:
map((response: Response) => {  return response.json(); })